# The XML code runs properly, but junit fails with NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, junit, eclipse-3.4, xsltc

I am upgrading my environment from eclipse 3.3.1 and java 1.4 to eclipse 3.4.1 and java 1.5.
My unit tests are in jUnit 3.

eclipse java version 1.5.0__17

stand alone env version 1.5.0__12, or 1.5.0-17, both work.

I have a method on a class that writes an XML file to disk.
It calls TransformerFactory tf = [javax.xml.transform.]TransformerFactory.newInstance();
When I run the code outside of eclipse it runs fine.
When I run the code in jUnit in eclipse I get the stack trace below.
The missing class is in the rt.jar of java 1.4 and not in java 5, but shouldn't that be abstracted from me?

How can I make the test pass?

I get the same error when I run the code in eclipse from an application.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xalan/processor/TransformerFactoryImpl
 at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryTransformerFactory.(RegistryTransformerFactory.java:62)
 at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXTransformerFactory.(RegistrySAXTransformerFactory.java:12)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
 at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:100)
 at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:278)
 at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:185)
 at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:103)
 at com.bellsouth.snt.cnmp.sso.netcool.NetcoolAccessThread.writeXmlFile(NetcoolAccessThread.java:278)
 at com.bellsouth.snt.cnmp.sso.netcool.NetcoolAccessThreadTest.testWriteXmlFile(NetcoolAccessThreadTest.java:83)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
 at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

**update**
I did some more research in the bowels of the stack trace. The working versions (outside eclipse) are returning an instance of com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl which is the fallback impl class name in  javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance()

```
    public static TransformerFactory newInstance()
        throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError {
        try {
            return (TransformerFactory) FactoryFinder.find(
            /* The default property name according to the JAXP spec */
            "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
            /* The fallback implementation class name, XSLTC */
            "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
        } catch (FactoryFinder.ConfigurationError e) {
            throw new TransformerFactoryConfigurationError(
                e.getException(),
                e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following line to setup of the unittest

```
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

I figured out what to do with a bit of RTFM.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance()

Answer (score 1):

You could check if you are running with the same Java version when running in Eclipse as when running outside of it (in Eclipse: Run As -> Run Configuration... -> JRE tab).

Comment: same version (some of the time) the question is updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Xalan JAR to the classpath.

Also see [here](http://bugs.gridsphere.org/browse/GPF-307) if you are using WebLogic. You'll have to put the JAR in shared/lib.

Comment: Why does it run outside of eclipse then? I haven't added the xalan jar to my java path.

Comment: To try to narrow down the probable causes, just add the Xalan JAR. Then hopefully you can get it to work, and you'll know better what to look for when comparing the different runtime environments.